# Regex for date in format hour.minute dayName day/month

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date, input

I am trying to verify `str` with the code below. My final goal is to allow this style of input:

> 18.30 Saturday_lastMatch 3/10

However, the code I have can't even work for the basic usage (98.5% `str` will be of this format):

> 19.30 Friday 15/5

```
var regex= /[0-9]{2}[\.:][0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{4,7} [0-9]\/[0-9]{2}/;
if(!str.match(regex)) {
  //"Bad format, match creation failed!");
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @anubhava see my update!

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]{4,7}` won't match `Saturday` or anything with an underscore in it?  I believe "Saturday" contains 8 letters.

Comment: @MikeSamuel yes I want to make it work for the basic usage first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your regex.

1. The date & time matching portions at the beginning and end don't allow for 1 *or* 2 digit numbers as they should.
2. You may want to consider anchoring the regex at the beginning and end with `^` and `$`, respectively.
3. The literal dot in the character class doesn't need to be escaped.

Try this:

```
var regex= /^[0-9]{1,2}[.:][0-9]{1,2} [A-Z][a-z]{5,8} [0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$/;
```

Comment: I am new to regex. Why the anchor?

Comment: @gsamaras Beginning of line anchor will prevent matches when there is leading text. End of line anchor will prevent matches when there is trailing text.

Comment: Asaph sorry for asking again, but that's not clear. An example maybe can help? Also, I still think that `{4,7}` should be `{5, 8}`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @gsamaras Basically, the `[A-Z]` part covers the single uppercase character and the `[a-z]{4,7}` part covers the remaining lowercase letters. Example: for the word `Saturday`, `[A-Z]` matches `S` and `[a-z]{4,7}` matches `aturday`. Make sense?

Comment: Asaph I agree. Take Wednesday. Doesn't that need 8 instead of 7? Also, take Friday, it needs 5, because with 4, I could write Fiday and still be OK.

Answer (score 3):

The final part of your regular expression that checks day/month needs to be expanded.  It currently only matches `#/##`, but it should allow `##/#` as well.  The simplest fix would be to allow either one or two digits on either side (e.g. 12/31)

```
var regex= /[0-9]{2}[\.:][0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{4,7} [0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}/;
```